# how to resolve akka.stream.Graph sink error akka stream using akka typed

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-typed

i am new in akka streams and akka typed my code was working fine with classic akka 
here is what i am doing

```
class FlowActor extends Actor{
  val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)

  def receive: Receive = {
    case word: String =>
      val replyTo = word.capitalize
      log.info("Actor {}, Capitalizing {}",context.self.path, replyTo)
      sender() ! replyTo
  }
}

val source = Source(List("hello","from","akka","streams!"))
val flowActor = system.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(10).props(Props[FlowActor]), "flowActor")
val flow = Flow[String].mapAsync(parallelism = 5)(elem => (flowActor ? elem).mapTo[String])
// sent from actor to stream to "ack" processing of given element
    val AckMessage = AckingReceiver.Ack

    // sent from stream to actor to indicate start, end or failure of stream:
    val InitMessage = AckingReceiver.StreamInitialized
    val OnCompleteMessage = AckingReceiver.StreamCompleted
    val onErrorMessage = (ex: Throwable) => AckingReceiver.StreamFailure(ex)

    val receiver = system.actorOf(Props(new SimpleAckingReceiver(AckMessage)), name = "recevier")

    val sink = Sink.actorRefWithBackpressure(
      receiver,
      onInitMessage = InitMessage,
      ackMessage = AckMessage,
      onCompleteMessage = OnCompleteMessage,
      onFailureMessage = onErrorMessage
    )

    val stream = source.via(flow).to(sink)
    stream.run()
```

and in the output i am getting the expected result 
now when i shift from akka classic to akka actors and done something like this

```
object FlowActor {
  val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)
  val FlowServiceKey = ServiceKey[FlowActor.TransformText]("FlowActor")

  sealed trait Command
  final case class TransformText(text: String, replyTo: ActorRef[TextTransformed]) extends Command with CborSerializable
  final case class TextTransformed(text: String) extends CborSerializable

  def apply(): Behavior[Command] =
    Behaviors.setup { ctx =>
      // each worker registers themselves with the receptionist
      ctx.log.info("Registering myself with receptionist")
      ctx.system.receptionist ! Receptionist.Register(FlowServiceKey, ctx.self)

      Behaviors.receiveMessage {
        case TransformText(text, replyTo) =>
          replyTo ! TextTransformed(text.capitalize)
          Behaviors.same
      }
    }
}

object SinkActor {

  sealed trait Event
  case object StartWork extends Event
  trait Ack
  object Ack extends Ack

  trait Protocol
  case class Init(ackTo: ActorRef[Ack]) extends Protocol
  case class Message(ackTo: ActorRef[Ack], msg: String) extends Protocol
  case object Complete extends Protocol
  case class Fail(ex: Throwable) extends Protocol
def apply(actorMaterializer: ActorMaterializer): Behavior[Event] = Behaviors.setup { ctx =>
    implicit val mat = actorMaterializer
    implicit val timeout=Timeout(5, SECONDS)
  Behaviors.receiveMessage {
    case STartWork=>
  val ref = ctx
        .spawn( (FlowActor()) ,"flowActor"
        )
        import FlowActor._
        val askFlow: Flow[String, TextTransformed, NotUsed] =
          ActorFlow.ask(ref)(TransformText.apply)
def targetActor(): ActorRef[Protocol] = ???

        val actor: ActorRef[Protocol] = targetActor()

        val source = Source(List("hello","from","akka","streams!"))

        val sink: Sink[String, NotUsed] = ActorSink.actorRefWithBackpressure(
          ref = actor,
          onCompleteMessage = Complete,
          onFailureMessage = Fail.apply,
          messageAdapter = Message.apply,
          onInitMessage = Init.apply,
          ackMessage = Ack)

        val stream = source.via(askFlow).runWith(sink)
Behaviors.same
    }
  }
  }
```

on the last line i am getting a compile time error

```
found   : akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink[String,akka.NotUsed]
[error]  
required: akka.stream.Graph[akka.stream.SinkShape[sample.cluster.akkastreams.FlowActor.TextTransformed],?]
[error]         val stream = source.via(askFlow).runWith(sink)
```

what i

please guide what am i missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the code tries to connect a `Flow` that emits `FlowActor.TextTransformed` elements to a `Sink` that expects `String` elements. It needs to convert the `TextTransformed` data to `String` objects:

```
val stream = source.via(askFlow)
    .map(element => element.text) // or equivalently: .map(_.text)
    .runWith(sink)
```

There are at least two other possible ways to do this, but I think the example above is the best approach, at least for more realistic and complex applications.

1. `FlowActor` could reply with `String` directly, instead of `TextTransformed`, by changing the type of the `replyTo` field in `TransformText` to `ActorRef[String]`. This would be closer to how the original classic example works, but it's a good practice to use wrapper types like `TextTransformed` in actor protocols, as it improves type safety and can make it easier to evolve the protocol.
2. The sink could expect `TextTransformed` elements rather than `String`, either by having the `messageAdaptor` function handle unwrapping the `String` from the `TextTransformed` object, or by having the `Message` class use `TextTransformed` instead of `String` in its `msg` field. The drawback of this approach is that it tightly couples the sink to the flow.